# Problem naming NSTableColumn

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview, nstablecolumn

I'm trying to create a column with an empty string as the identifier but Cocoa seems to replace the empty string with the word "Field" every time I try to create the column. How do you go around this?

```
- (void)addColumnWithCheckboxToTable:(NSTableView *)table
{
    // Add column with checkbox before all other columns
    // This column will have no title and should be as wide as the checkbox
    NSTableColumn *column = [[[NSTableColumn alloc] initWithIdentifier:@" "] autorelease];

    // The checkbox is to be initialised without a title
    NSButtonCell *checkbox = [[[NSButtonCell alloc] initTextCell:@" "] autorelease];
    [checkbox setEditable:YES];
    [checkbox setButtonType:NSSwitchButton];
    [checkbox setImagePosition:NSImageOnly];
    [checkbox setControlSize:NSSmallControlSize];

    // Add column with checkbox to table
    [column setDataCell:checkbox];

    // Add column to table
    [table addTableColumn:column];
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A column's identifier is not the same thing as its title. You want to set its -headerCell's string value:

```
[[columnColumn headerCell] setStringValue:@""];
```

Comment: I think it's rather unintuitive in code. NSControl and subclasses pass messages on to their cells. I think an NSTableColumn should have a -title/-setTitle: method that passes the string on to the header cell's string value. Someone should file an enhancement request ... but I'm too lazy to. :-)